# The contains of the window appears on the contains of the page at the same time: WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I am really beginner with programming therefore, I face with a lot of errors.

In the following solution I've one identification **Window** and one update user's information **Page**, when i click the button on the identification **Window**, the contains of the Window and the contains of the Page appear on each other at the same time, this is what i neither want nor can fix it. What i want, is: when the user clicks the button on the identification **Window**, the window's contain should show only page's contain. Thanks a lot for your help!

Window XML Code:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Margin="0,8" Width="385" >
        <Frame x:Name="Main"/>

        <StackPanel Margin="10 10 10 20" 
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Width="357">
            <Label Content="User Name:"/>
            <TextBox Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
            <Label Content="Your Password"/>
            <PasswordBox Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        Margin="10">
                <Button x:Name="ForUpdate"
                        Content="Match"
                        Click="Update"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

The button event handler C# Code:

```
    private void Update(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        Main.Content = new UpdateCio();
     }
```

Page XML Code:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Label Content="this is test!"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi, usually we don't switch the content of a Window for another but open a new Window and close (or not) the previous one.

For me the code you showed failed when I clicked the button so I'm not sure how UpdateCio is defined for you.
****      
            UpdateCio updateCio = new UpdateCio();
            updateCio.Show();
            this.Close();
****     

Of course it depends on what you are trying to achive.
Is there a particular reason you wanted to swap content ?

Comment: hey thanks for your reply! the reason is: this Window is for updating the owner of the application's data (Information). When he/she opens this window, the password is required, if it is true, then he can update his information. I just used the Page, in order to avoid using too many windows in application. Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: After some time I think I understood but I think there is some important code/xaml not shown which makes it difficult to understand. UpdateCio.xaml is a Page right ?

Comment: only the window contains like namespaces i have not posted it! i can post the entire page's and window's contain, should i?

Comment: No it's ok, I think I understood, I will post an answer and you can correct me if I didn't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you are trying to use a Frame in which you place a Page in order to not open a new Window.

In order to make the Page appear in the Frame, you are suppose to use the "Navigate" method not set the content property (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.frame?view=netcore-3.1).
(Otherwise if you just want to set the Content, you should use a ContentPresenter).

So Update would become :

```
private void Update(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Navigate(new UpdateCio());
    }
```

What this is saying is that the Page "UpdateCio.xaml" should be shown inside the Frame :

```
<Frame x:Name="Main"/>
```

It will not replace the rest of the xaml code you define so it apppears behind the other stackPanel.

You could change the position of th Frame and the xaml of UpdateCio so that it appears on top and hides the rest of the window behind it. (A bit hacky).

Or you could really use the Frames and Pages and the navigation system and define a MainWindow in which different pages would appear).

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <Frame x:Name="Main"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Set the initial page (you could also do it in xaml by setting the Source property of the Frame
        Main.Navigate(new IdentificationPage());
    }
}
```

IdentificationPage.xaml (the xaml you had in your Window minus the Frame + it becomes a Page instead of a Window).

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Margin="10 10 10 20" 
                Orientation="Vertical"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Width="357">
        <Label Content="User Name:"/>
        <TextBox Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
        <Label Content="Your Password"/>
        <PasswordBox Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    Margin="10">
            <Button x:Name="ForUpdate"
                    Content="Match"
                    Click="Update"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

IdentificationPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class IdentificationPage : Page
{
    public IdentificationPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Update(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //From a page, you have to use "NavigationService to Navigate"
        //(the .Navigate method appear only if the class inherits from Page)
        NavigationService.Navigate(new UpdateCio());
    }
}
```

UpdateCio.xaml which is still a Page and not a Window (this is what got me confused at first):

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Label Content="this is test!"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

UpdateCio.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class UpdateCio : Page
{
    public UpdateCio()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Let me know which solution you chose in the end.

Comment: What is the error message ? Did you change the xaml of UpdateCio.xaml and IdentificationPage.xaml to make it a Page instead of a Window ? ("<Page x:Class="WpfApp2.UpdateCio" ..." at the top). WpfApp2 being the name of my solution